# checked/uncheck the value of material ui checkbox based on data(hooks) that returns Y(true/checked) react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to check/uncheck the value of checkbox upon Edit(Modal) based on the return of addAdvisory(hooks) which is 'Y'-means true/checked.

Here's my simple code:

```js
const [addAdvisory, setaddAdvisory] = useState({
    SYSTEMID: '',
    WITHOTHERSYSTEM: '',
    DATEFROM: '',
    DATETO: '',
    DOWNTIMEREASON: '',
    AFFECTEDSYSTEMS: '',
    AFFECTEDMODULES: '',
    DATEOFRELEASE: '',
    TIME: '',
    ADVISORYDESC: '',
    ADVISORYMESSAGE: '',
    ADVISORYID:''
})

const openCloseModalEdit = () =>{
    setModalEdit(!modalEdit);   
}

//function upon clicking Edit button 
const selectedAdvisory=(ADVISORYID,action1) =>{
    setaddAdvisory(ADVISORYID);
    (action1==='Edit') ? openCloseModalEdit() : openCloseModalDelete();
    console.log("For Editing: ", addAdvisory)
}

//components inside modal edit
const bodyEdit = (
    <FormControl className={style.FormControl}>
    <FormControlLabel 
        control={
            <Checkbox 
                checked={<i want to return true/false here to check/uncheck the textbox}
                onChange={checkboxSystemChange}
                name='checkedSystem'
                color = 'primary'
            />
        }
        label = 'is there other system/s affected?'
        />
    </FormControl>
)
```

Please help me with this, newbie on reactjs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const [checkVal, setCheckVal] = useState('Y');

const bodyEdit = (
    <FormControlLabel 
    control={
        <Checkbox 
            checked={checkVal === 'Y' ? true : false}
            onChange={()=>{setCheckVal(checkVal === 'Y' ? 'N' : 'Y')}}
            name='checkedSystem'
            color = 'primary'
        />
    }
    </FormControl>
)
```

Please check above code.

Comment: Hi @artem-medianyk I'm having hard time integrating it to my existing codes. I have addAdvisory(see codes above) that stores 'Y/N' value from DB upon edit and I have checkboxSystemChange that holds onChange function see below code

addAdvisory = stores Y/N from DB

const [statecheckboxSystem, setstatecheckboxSystem]=useState({checkedSystem: false)}

const checkboxSystemChange=(e)=>{
setstatecheckboxSystem({statecheckboxSystem,[e.target.name]:e.target.checked})
if(stateCheckboxSystem.checkedSystem != true)
setaddAdvisory(prevState=>({...prevState,'WITHOTHERSYSTEM':'Y'})else...

TYIA

Comment: please show me the full code in your code box